# Rsnapshot still running even with a full disk - no errors in log

Tags: linux, backup, rsnapshot

Im a very new admin(intern) without anyone to show me the job.  The company i work for use rsnaphot to do their backups.  Here's their filesystem (CentOs) :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda3             184G  140G   35G  81% /

tmpfs                 2.3G     0  2.3G   0% /lib/init/rw

udev                  2.3G  212K  2.3G   1% /dev

tmpfs                 2.3G     0  2.3G   0% /dev/shm

/dev/sda1             4.6G  156M  4.2G   4% /boot

/dev/sda4              33G  176M   31G   1% /tmp

/dev/sdb1             1.8T  1.8T     0 100% /media/backupInterne

/dev/sdd1             917G  470G  401G  54% /media/Data
```

The sdb1 disk is used to do a backup of sdd1 disk.  The rsnapshot schedule is like that :

```
hourly : 24

daily : 30

weekly : 4

monthly :12
```

When i saw the full disk, i went to see if any errors were appearing in the logs, but nothing.  In fact, every cron job is happening as if nothing was wrong.  How is that even possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities here.

1. Linux filesystems with their default configuration have a certain percentage (5% I believe) of space "reserved" for the root user. If rsnapshot is being run as root, it actually has more space available than tools will report.
2. If there are not many changes happening, the **vast** majority of rsnapshot's work is accomplished using links, which don't take up disk space.

Comment: Thanks!  Found out how much real space was left (yikes!) and my boss just calm down a little :)

Comment: @littleadmin - You're welcome! So it was #1 that applied to your circumstance, correct?

Comment: Yes, i totally forgot about that reserved space. Thanks again

Comment: @littleadmin - You're welcome! Glad I could help.